# Find a space in a string and then split into number and text into separate column in python

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe with one column 'col' where the cell contains string and text. Data looks like:[image: Data]

The problem is that some string cell contain text and number with spaces in between but some string contain text and string without space.

[image: Problem]

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['File-Checking.xlsx']))
df
#Method 1
if (df[df['col'].str.contains('')]) == True:
  df[['col1','col2']] = df['col'].str.split().apply(lambda x: sorted(x)).apply(pd.Series) #working fine
else: #Add a space and then separate into text and number
  df[['col1','col2'] = df['col']
```

Two method came in my mind to solve this issue.

1. if-else statement: if there is a space then split the column, otherwise add a space between text and number first, then separate into text and number(else part).(Implemented Above)

2.Make a new column where the code just copy the cell where the space are present but if there is no space is present then put spaces between text and number into new column.

Can anyone help me?

Google Colab : [Code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t71IFmo2dcAbIWdH6aR9VMjcG1CKk96W?usp=sharing)

Excel File : [Attach](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c_wqSFViOnRNhQa2xh-RqrU8fu5s5pEB/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the floats and strings:

```
df['number'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
df['text'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+)')
```

Output:

|  | col | number | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 62.9 YWT | 62.9 | YWT |
| 1 | HWT 284 | 284 | HWT |
| 2 | PWT62.5 | 62.5 | PWT |
| 3 | HWT140 | 140 | HWT |
| 4 | 60.4PWT | 60.4 | PWT |
| 5 | 62.9 PT | 62.9 | PT |